# send_to cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

The error is  **`send_to` cannot be resolved or is not a field**

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

        }
    });
```

I have tried by importing but its still not working 
`import your.application.packagename.R;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
<string name="send_to">Hello world!</string>
```

inside **string.xml** that is located inside **res -> values -> strings.xml** folder of your project. Or instead of `Hello world!` you can use your own text if  you want.

or else also you can use this following way

replace your

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

with

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Hello World!"));
```